# OpenGL DevIL c++ source code

Tags: c++, image, opengl, textures

After spending hours searching for a simple way to to add an image to an openGL application written in C++, i failed, miserably. It is also apparent that many others have too.

I am fairly new to OpenGL, I have written my own win32 app with OpenGL using DevIL and you guessed it, i failed.
The only way i could get DevIL to work was using Glut, which i dont want to use, or SDL or glaux.h

What i am looking for is code or a tutorial for a simple image loader in C++ with OpenGL and DevIL, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How was DevIL not working?  Crash?  Linker problems?  Nothing useful displayed?

Comment: No texture was drawn to the screen. Its basically the same code as the glut demo which is here:

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking OpenGL to filter using mapmaps make sure to [give it mipmaps to filter with](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture).

Also, I'm pretty sure `glTexParameteri()` and `glTexEnvf()` only apply to the currently bound texture.

Try replacing your `InitTextures()` with this:

```
Tex1 = ilutGLLoadImage("tex1.bmp");
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Tex1 );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

Tex2 = ilutGLLoadImage("tex2.bmp");
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Tex2 );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

Comment: The code from pastebin works fine with glut, I want to replicate that code as a win32 app with opengl, not using glut.
Im really at a loss of how to go about it, all the tutorials i have seen include glut or ones like NeHes tutorials which use the glaux lib.
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06
I want to swap out the glaux lib functions in that tutorial for the DevIL lib, But im not sure how to go about it as i do not have a proper understanding of DevIL? Is it possible?